# Flutter ClassNotFoundException (java.lang.RuntimeException) crash error in play console?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play-console

Recently, I uploaded my Flutter app to Play Store. My app crashed after installing and opening the app. I've got several Crash Reports. I did research everywhere about this error and found nothing, I even contacted Google Play's Support.
I have already added in `build.gradle` file this below line but steel occur above error in play store I couldn't find a solution and my app crashes on every device?

```
logs

    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2824)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3010)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1707)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:192)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6759)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:556)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:875)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1179)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2814)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3010)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1707)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:192)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6759)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:556)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:875)
        

    ndk {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64','arm64 ,v8a'}

build.gradle
  
    def localProperties = new Properties()
        def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
        if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
                localProperties.load(reader)
            }
        }
        
        def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
        if (flutterRoot == null) {
        //    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
        }
        
        def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
        if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
            flutterVersionCode = '1'
        }
        
        def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
        if (flutterVersionName == null) {
            flutterVersionName = '1.0'
        }
        
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
        apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
        
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 30
            sourceSets {
                main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            }
        
            lintOptions {
                disable 'InvalidPackage'
            }
        
        
            defaultConfig {
                // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
                applicationId "com.muhammadali.a_Store"
                minSdkVersion 20
                targetSdkVersion 30
                versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
                versionName flutterVersionName
                multiDexEnabled true
                ndk {
                    abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
                }
            }
        
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                    // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                }
            }
        }
        
        flutter {
            source '../..'
        }
        
        
        
        dependencies {
        //    implementation(name: 'razorpay-amazonpay-1.3.0', ext: 'aar')
        //    implementation(name:'PayWithAmazon', ext:'aar')
            //noinspection GradleCompatible-
        //    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"
            implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-core', version: '1.21.0'
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        //    implementation "com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.5.3"
        }
        
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: provide the log!

Comment: minSdkVersion 21 and https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex